# Handlebars confusion I don't get it

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have tried my best to debug thoroughly but i just can't figure out why this code does not work.. I know its my fault but i can't find the bug. Please help me guys

https://codepen.io/blaze4dem/pen/zZmqKa

```
    var docs = document.getElementById('pag_temp').innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(docs);

Handlebars.registerHelper("makeradio", function(name, options){
      var radioList = options.fn();
      radioList = radioList.trim().split("\n");

      var output = "";
      for(var val in radioList){
        var item = radioList(val).trim();
      output += '<input type="radio" name="'+ name +'" value="'+ item +'"> '+ item + '<br/>';
      };
      return output;
    });

    var tempdata = template({});
    document.getElementById('dynamic').innaHTML += tempdata;
```

Answer (score 1):

I see 3 issues in the code.

- `for in` is best to iterate over objects. In this case when you split the output is an array. User `for` loop instead.
- You have a typo, when you are replacing the element. Supposed to be `innerHTML`
- radioList(val) --> `()` will invoke a method, where as you want to access a property. So it has to be `[]`.

You can try this approach. But I strongly feel that you should be using a different delimiter instead of `\n`

```
var docs = document.getElementById('pag_temp').innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(docs);

Handlebars.registerHelper("makeradio", function(name, options) {
  debugger;
  var radioList = options.fn();
  var hasSpaces = radioList.indexOf(' ') > -1;
  var hasNewLines = radioList.indexOf('\n') > -1;

  if (hasNewLines) {
    radioList = radioList.trim().split("\n");
  } else if (hasSpaces) {
    radioList = radioList.trim().split(" ");
  }

  var output = "";
  // for in is best to iterate over objects.
  // use for loop instead
  for (var i = 0; i < radioList.length; i++) {
    var item = radioList[i].trim();
    output += '<input type="radio" name="' + name + '" value="' + item + '"> ' + item + '<br/>';
  };
  return output;
});

var tempdata = template({});
document.getElementById('dynamic').innerHTML += tempdata;
```

**[Check Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o7jzayLg/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer bro, But i have no idea all the code you just wrote. I am actually just learning to use javascript and Handlebars. 
I am actually following a video tutorial, In the tutorial the code above works fine but mine is not working... I tried to debug but i don't understand what the bug means (is not a function). 

I am wondering if its because in the video tutorial the handlebars version is v4.0.2 while mine is v4.0.5.

Comment: It must be `radioList(val)` . Because `radioList` is not a function on which you can invoke using `()`.  `[ ]` is used for property access. `var obj = {  a : 10 };` You can access the value of `a` by using `obj['a']  or obj.a` which spits out a value of 10.   But if you instead try to access it using `obj()` it will fail with the error that you have seen.